# Custom drawer animation is not smooth in Jetpack Compose android

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, navigation-drawer, android-jetpack

I developed a custom drawer that behave like a Top sheet. Everything is good but I try to Drag up the drawer, the animation is not smooth when drawer slide up (exit), Animation stuck for a second when slide up and then Card disappears. Following is my code for custom drawer in Jetpack compose.

```
var offsetX by remember { mutableFloatStateOf(0f) }
var offsetY by remember { mutableFloatStateOf(0f) }
var isDrawerVisible by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
var direction by remember { mutableIntStateOf(-1) }
// ** Drawer **
    AnimatedVisibility(
        visible = isDrawerVisible,
        enter = slideInVertically(),
        exit = slideOutVertically()
    ) {

        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .offset { IntOffset(0, offsetY.toInt()) }
                .pointerInput(Unit) {
                    coroutineScope {
                        detectDragGestures(
                            onDragEnd = {
                                Timber.d("DRAG_DEBUG:: Drag End")
                                if (direction == 2) {
                                    offsetY = 0f
                                    isDrawerVisible = false
                                }
                                else if (direction == 1) {
                                    offsetY = 0f
                                }
                            }
                        )
                        { change, dragAmount ->
                            change.consume()

                            val (_, y) = dragAmount
                            when {
                                y > 0 -> {
                                    direction = 1
                                }

                                y < 0 -> {
                                    direction = 2
                                }
                            }

                            offsetX += dragAmount.x
                            if ((offsetY + dragAmount.y) <= 0) {
                                offsetY += dragAmount.y
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                .fillMaxWidth()
        ) {
            Card(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                shape = RoundedCornerShape(bottomStart = 10.dp, bottomEnd = 10.dp),
                colors = CardDefaults.cardColors(
                    containerColor = Color.White
                ),
                elevation = CardDefaults.cardElevation(
                    defaultElevation = 5.dp
                ),
            ) {
                Column (modifier = Modifier.padding(15.dp)) {

                    Row(verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically) {

                        Image(
                            modifier = Modifier.clickable { isDrawerVisible = false },
                            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.icon_drawer_close),
                            contentDescription = stringResource(id = R.string.text_close)
                        )

                        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))

                        Image(
                            modifier = Modifier.height(53.dp),
                            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.icon_drawer_logo),
                            contentDescription = stringResource(id = R.string.text_close),
                            contentScale = ContentScale.FillHeight
                        )

                        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))

                        Icon(
                            modifier = Modifier.size(50.dp),
                            imageVector = Icons.Default.Close, contentDescription = "",
                            tint = Color.White
                        )

                    }

                    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(10.dp))

                    LazyVerticalGrid(
                        columns = GridCells.Fixed(4)
                    ) {
                        items(viewModel.getDrawerList(context)) {
                            Column(
                                modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 15.dp),
                                horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
                                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
                            ) {
                                Image(
                                    painter = painterResource(id = it.icon),
                                    contentDescription = ""
                                )
                                MyText(
                                    modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 5.dp),
                                    text = it.title,
                                    fontSize = 13.sp
                                )
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(25.dp))

                    Image(
                        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().height(4.dp),
                        painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.icon_drawer_bar),
                        contentDescription = "",
                        contentScale = ContentScale.FillHeight
                    )
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

and inside viewmodel the list code is:

```
    fun getDrawerList(context: Context): List<DrawerModel> {
    val drawerItemTitle = context.resources.getStringArray(R.array.drawer_menu_item)

    return listOf(
        DrawerModel(0, drawerItemTitle[0], R.drawable.icon_drawer_profile),
        DrawerModel(1, drawerItemTitle[1], R.drawable.icon_drawer_payment),
        DrawerModel(2, drawerItemTitle[2], R.drawable.icon_drawer_booking),
        DrawerModel(3, drawerItemTitle[3], R.drawable.icon_drawer_history),
        DrawerModel(4, drawerItemTitle[4], R.drawable.icon_drawer_setting),
        DrawerModel(5, drawerItemTitle[5], R.drawable.icon_drawer_contact_us),
        DrawerModel(6, drawerItemTitle[6], R.drawable.icon_drawer_referral),
        DrawerModel(7, drawerItemTitle[7], R.drawable.icon_drawer_places)
    )
}
```

and code for arrays.xml is:

```
    <array name="drawer_menu_item">
    <item>@string/text_profile</item>
    <item>@string/text_payments</item>
    <item>@string/bookings</item>
    <item>@string/text_history</item>
    <item>@string/text_settings</item>
    <item>@string/support</item>
    <item>@string/text_referral</item>
    <item>@string/places</item>
</array>
```

Please suggest about how I get smooth the slide out (exit) animation. Following is the image of drawer:
[image]

Comment: Not sure i found this today on linked in https://taskito.io/dev/android-topsheet

Comment: No @Raghunandan its not helping link.